# Is there such a thing as a 'not' constraint operator?

Tags: haskell, constraints, typeclass

Say I want to write a function for flattening lists, lists of lists, lists of lists of lists, etc. to just lists. I could write the following:

```
{-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilies #-}
class Flattenable a where
  type Flattened a
  flatten :: a -> Flattened a

instance NotFlattenable a => Flattenable [a] where
  type Flattened [a] = [a]
  flatten = id

instance Flattenable a => Flattenable [a] where
  type Flattened [a] = Flattened a
  flatten = concat . map flatten
```

Where `NotFlattenable a` is some constraint restricting to those `a` without an instance of `Flattenable`. Is `NotFlattenable` a legitimate constraint? How would I go about writing it? (Note that the absence of a `NotFlattenable` constraint would make the two instances overlap)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, this isn't possible since Haskell's type classes are always open: the compiler can never prove some instance does *not* exist, since somebody might still add it any time later.

Comment: Sorry for short answer, this still needs mention of closed type families and `OverlappingInstances` trickery.

Comment: `OverlappingInstances` is yucky.

Comment: If you are happy with a closed class `Flattenable` you can hack something up using closed type families.

Comment: @augustss, would it be possible to elaborate?